# Warning: function result variable of a managed type does not seem to be initialized

Tags: arrays, record, pascal, freepascal

The task I have requires me to create two routines one of which reads in data from a terminal and the other outputs data to the terminal, and another two routines which utilize an array to loop through these two routines to perform them multiple times.

The issue I am having is that the terminal crashes after one run through of the `ReadComputer` function instead of looping multiple times. The compiler is also providing me the following warning:

> "Warning: function result variable of a managed type does not seem to be initialized"

although after extensive research and due to the fact that no one uses pascal I cannot find a solution. Any help is much appreciated! :)

I have provided a copy of my code here for reference:

```
program CompupterProgram;
uses TerminalUserInput;
type 
    Computer = Record
        id: integer;
        manafacturer: String;
        year: integer;
        warranty: integer;
    end;

type Computers = Array of Computer;

function ReadComputer(): Computer;
begin
    ReadComputer.id := ReadInteger('PLease Enter Computer Id:');
    ReadComputer.manafacturer := ReadString('PLease Enter Computer Manafacturer:');
    ReadComputer.year := ReadInteger('PLease Enter Computer Year:');
    ReadComputer.warranty := ReadInteger('PLease Enter Computer Warranty:');
    result := ReadComputer;
end;

procedure WriteComputer(c: Computer);
begin
    WriteLn('Computer ID: ', c.id);
    WriteLn('Computer Manafacturer ', c.manafacturer);
    WriteLn('Computer Year ', c.year);
    WriteLn('Computer Warranty ', c.warranty);
    ReadLn();
end;

function ReadAllComputers(count: Integer): Computers;
var i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to count do
    begin
        ReadAllComputers[i] := ReadComputer();
    end;
result := ReadAllComputers;
end;

procedure WriteAllComputers(computerArray: Computers);
var i: Integer;
begin
    for i:= 0 to (length(computerArray)) do
    begin
        WriteComputer(computerArray[i]);
    end;
end;

procedure Main();
var computers: Array of Computer;
    index: Integer;
begin
    computers := ReadAllComputers(3);
    WriteAllComputers(computers);
end;

begin
Main();
end.
```

Comment: Your code has a few errors. You write off the end of the arrays. These are zero based. So valid indices are 0 to N-1 inclusive. You access index N in both your loops. Secondly, you don't allocate the array. You need to call `SetLength` in `ReadAllComputers`. Finally, Result := ReadAllComputers does nothing. They both refer to the same variable. My advice is to use `Result` always. It's more clear, and less verbose.

Comment: Thanks a tonne the SetLength in ReadAllComputers solved the issue, much appreciated!

Comment: Well, you need to fix the out of bounds array access also

Comment: I had the loops set to stop at (n-1) as well before, I was experimenting with the code and then copy and pasted it here which is why that is not there I have made all the changes, thanks again!

Comment: Why "unfortunately"? I don't know a language in which it is easier to express a problem (and its solution) than Pascal, especially Object Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

`Computers` is a dynamic array, and you need to set its length before use in `ReadAllComputers` with `SetLength()`.

All dynamic arrays are zero based, so you need to count from zero to `Length(aDynArray)-1` in a couple of places. Or use the [High(aDynArray)](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/high.html) function to express the highest possible value of it's index.

---

***Note:*** The `Result` use in `ReadComputer` is superfluous. Either use the function name or the `Result` variable to return the function result. The latter is to prefer, since code will be more clear.

*In freepascal the `Result` variable is defined only in ObjFPC or Delphi mode.*

Comment: FreePascal now has {$ModeSwitch Result} for function results, without affecting the other switches in a mode.